# string.replace( char, char)

Tags: c#, string, text

I wants to replace the character (") with the character ("") in the below string.

```
string str = @"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
 <GetResources xmlns="http://www.example.com">
 </GetResources>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"
```

i have tried str.replace( '"' , '""');
but it does not satisfy.

Some other way?

Comment: Did you assign the result of the replace to anything? It doesn't modify the original string.

Comment: *"but it does not satisfy"* What is that even supposed to mean?

Comment: show the code you have so we can either see the issue or recreate the problem.

Comment: And FYI, `""` is not a character, it's two - hence a *string* of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it in VS and this works for me:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
```

It replaces all " with "" in my textbox.

Comment: Can you please explain bit about the escape sequence?

Comment: \" is used to escape double quotes. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your double quotes.

```
str.replace( "\"" ,"\"\"")
```